# How can I change the color of digits when using the listings package?

Tags: listings, color

I'm using the [listings](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package and was already able to modify the color of the keywords and almost all elements I was interested in. The only thing that remains is the color of the digits. I'd like to have all numbers within my source codes to be coloured in red. Do you know any smart way of doing this ?

I was able to change the colour of single digits but not of whole numbers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An interesting problem would be to only color digits in the source, and not in strings or comments.

Comment: Also see [coloring digits within listings, but not in strings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34896/coloring-digits-with-the-listings-package/34952#34952)

Answer (score 20):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{literate=%
    {0}{{{\color{red}0}}}1
    {1}{{{\color{red}1}}}1
    {2}{{{\color{red}2}}}1
    {3}{{{\color{red}3}}}1
    {4}{{{\color{red}4}}}1
    {5}{{{\color{red}5}}}1
    {6}{{{\color{red}6}}}1
    {7}{{{\color{red}7}}}1
    {8}{{{\color{red}8}}}1
    {9}{{{\color{red}9}}}1
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
This is a test
123 + 456 = 789
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Is it possible to change the hard-coded list of `{*}{{{\color{red}*}}}1` into a looping form?

Comment: This also colors numbers inside comments, though.

Comment: @Clément: Add a star before the zero, i.e. `{0}{{{\color{red}0}}}1 -> *{0}{{{\color{red}0}}}1` to only colour outside of strings and comments. You only need to do this once, so not for the rest of the numerals.

Comment: However, be aware that, with those literate replacements of digits, if you define identifiers containing digits, `listings` won't be able to recognise those identifiers as such. For instance, if you have `alsoletter={1},morekeywords={test1},keywordstyle=\color{blue}`, then Herbert's literate replacements will prevent `test8` from being coloured in blue.

Comment: @xport I know your question is old, but, if you're still interested, look at egreg's answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164442/how-can-i-redefine-my-macro-to-accept-a-charcode-instead-of-a-character

Comment: @Jubobs How can I only change the figures in only a flow?