# Coloring digits with the listings package

Tags: listings, color

I'm trying to typeset some python code, and I would like integer literals to be highlighted. I've come up, after about two hours of fighting with the documentation and various other questions here and on SO, with the following:

```
\lstset{ %
    language=Python,
    otherkeywords={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0},
    morekeywords=[2]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0},
    keywordstyle=[2]{\color{orange}},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{red},
}
```

Unfortunately, *that doesn't work*. Numbers found in strings are also highlighted, which is rather annoying, and not only are they highlighted: they are highlighted in `blue`. Numerals in regular program text, on the other hand, are rightly highlighted in `red`.

Help?

EDIT: Thanks Peter Grill for your very nice solution. Is there a way to not break string colouring, though? When I use you code, the `stringstyle=\color{red}` doesn't seem to work anymore (strings are just plain black). Similarly, comments can be enclosed in triple quotes in python, and if I adapt your quote to detect `"""` blocks, then the corresponding 
comments are not highlighted anymore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the color of digits when using the listings package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23634/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-digits-when-using-the-listings-package)

Comment: While code snippets are useful, it is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @lockstep Since Clément has commented already on the linked question, I don't think it's quite a duplicate.  Clément, it would be helpful if you showed how the linked solution doesn't work (and give a complete example.)

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for the late answer. The current answer seems perfect; sorry for not posting a MWE.

Comment: Please provide a full MWE that illustrates the new problem.

Comment: @Clément Please convert your edit into a comment here, or perhaps a new question linked to this one. We like to keep questions just for that, if possible.

Comment: @JosephWright Sorry, I followed the advice posted on prev answer

Comment: @Clément: My advice was that it was directly related to this specific question, then you should post a [MWE as described here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Related: [Color numbers only out of keywords](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217505/listings-color-numbers-only-out-of-keywords)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems that you want the coloring of the digits, but not when they are within a string.  If I correctly understand, you can use a conditional to define if we should apply the color or not. Then when we encounter a quote, we disable to coloring until the next quote.

Here I have disabled coloring within both single and double quotes. If this is not desired, simply comment out the corresponding line in `\lstset`.

[image]

Below I have used `newtoggle` from [the `etoolbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox) as I like that syntax much better than the `\newif` syntax. But if you don't want to include an additional package it should be pretty straightforward to adapt this to use `\newif` or [some other conditional methods](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build/33577#33577).

### Further Enhancements:

- If you desire to extend this to handle floating point numbers, and highlight the decimal separator (but not periods), see [Listings package: How can I format all numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32174/listings-package-how-can-i-format-all-numbers/32176#32176)
- A further enhancement would be to disable the coloring within comments in the code. However, this is dependent on the particular language being typeset, but a similar technique could be applied to disable coloring at the beginning of a comment and re enable it at the end of the comment.  This should be straightforward for comments that have a begin and end delimiter (i.e., `/* ... */` C-style comments), but for comments that go to end of  line (i.e., `//` C-style comments), the end of line will need to be detected and used to re enable comments.

### Simpler Solution:

- As @MarkS.Everitt points out in the comments, an alternative solution is available at: [Colored strings by listings package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42889/colored-strings-by-listings-package)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newtoggle{InString}{}% Keep track of if we are within a string
\togglefalse{InString}% Assume not initally in string

\newcommand*{\ColorIfNotInString}[1]{\iftoggle{InString}{#1}{\color{red}#1}}%
\newcommand*{\ProcessQuote}[1]{#1\iftoggle{InString}{\global\togglefalse{InString}}{\global\toggletrue{InString}}}%
\lstset{literate=%
    {"}{{{\ProcessQuote{"}}}}1% Disable coloring within double quotes
    {'}{{{\ProcessQuote{'}}}}1% Disable coloring within single quote
    {0}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{0}}}}1
    {1}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{1}}}}1
    {2}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{2}}}}1
    {3}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{3}}}}1
    {4}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{4}}}}1
    {5}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{5}}}}1
    {6}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{6}}}}1
    {7}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{7}}}}1
    {8}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{8}}}}1
    {9}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{9}}}}1
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily]
    These are colored 0123456789,
    but "these are not 0123456789"
    and 'these also are not 0123456789'
    again colored: 0123456789
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it's a great idea to have a toggle. However, I would image such a toggle to not be printed in the text since it merely represents a toggle. As such, it would probably some character that is not often used in the language. This is user-specific though.

Comment: @Werner: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean by "such a toggle to not be printed in the text"?  The intent here was to exclude coloring of digits in strings, so `"` defines the begin and end of a string.

Comment: Mmmm, I thought strings here might refer to keywords like `myvar1` or `func123` and the like. I may have been mistaken.

Comment: @Werner: Good point. I would think that that would be covered by keywords.  Another reason why we need a MWE to clarify questions.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for this thorough and detailed answer. I'll try it immediately.

Comment: Works very nice! Although, is there a way to also highlight strings?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "highlight string"? If this is directly related to this question you should update the question and provide a MWE. If it is not about coloring digits, then it should be a follow up question. You can refer to this question in that and explain what else you are looking for.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Clément: Did this solution not answer your original question?

Comment: @PeterGrill: You can do this more easily by adding a simple `*`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42895/9043

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: Thanks. I did not know about the `*` option and have added a link here to that question.

Comment: @PeterGrill: The problem with your answer was that it disabled string colouring; numbers were coloured, but strings lost their highlighting.

Comment: @Clément: Sorry, I did not understand what you had wanted earlier (seem obvious now that I see the other question). That is one reason why it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) instead of "describing" the symptom.

Comment: @Peter Grill: Amazing, thanks! I am trying to work on the enhancement with the comments, as you outlined it above. 
My question is [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117917/isodat-language-source-code-syntax-highlighting), please take a look! :)

Answer (score 10):

Here is a way of applying a style to digits (only outside strings and comments), that improves upon [Peter Grill's approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34952/21891) in two ways.

1. It is more flexible insofar as it allows you to specify additional replacements (of `<=` by `$\leq$`, for instance) to take effect *everywhere* in the code; that's handy because, in practice, you may want at least *some* literate replacements to also take place in comments (in particular) and in strings.
2. It is more robust insofar as it will work "out of the box", no matter how you define your string and comment delimiters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand\digitstyle{\color{red}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ProcessDigit}[1]
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode\relax%
   {\digitstyle #1}%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\lstset{literate=
    {0}{{{\ProcessDigit{0}}}}1
    {1}{{{\ProcessDigit{1}}}}1
    {2}{{{\ProcessDigit{2}}}}1
    {3}{{{\ProcessDigit{3}}}}1
    {4}{{{\ProcessDigit{4}}}}1
    {5}{{{\ProcessDigit{5}}}}1
    {6}{{{\ProcessDigit{6}}}}1
    {7}{{{\ProcessDigit{7}}}}1
    {8}{{{\ProcessDigit{8}}}}1
    {9}{{{\ProcessDigit{9}}}}1
    {<=}{{\(\leq\)}}1,
    morestring=[b]",
    morestring=[b]',
    morecomment=[l]//,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily]
    These are colored 0123456789,
    but "these are not 0123456789"
    and 'these also are not 0123456789'
    again colored: 0123456789
    // not colored: 0123456789
    Additional literate replacement:
    <= "<=" // comment 1 <= 2
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: could this somehow be made so that also keywords etc. are spared from being replaced? This apparently is not so in this version.

Comment: Yes, my current solution is not ideal because, as you've noticed, keyword containing digits will not be highlighted as such. I believe [that answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164297/21891) could be modified to improve this one, but you'd have to specify exactly what it is you want. For instance, would you want to color all numbers (including floating points) or just integers? Should 0x234 be highlighted as number? In any case, the asker apparently got his answer here. You should probably ask a fresh question that lists all your highlighting requirements.

Comment: @Jubobs Could it not be colored after some character, for example, I type A1, then the A1 is not colored red but if I type  only 1 then it is colored.