# How to color digits with the listings package

Tags: formatting, listings, color

For my project, I've been using the `listings` package in order to color the keywords, comments, strings, and digits in the code.

The thing is, I've managed to color the keywords, comments and strings, however, I couldn't color the digits within the code without coloring those in the comments/strings.

I've tried using the solution proposed in [Coloring digits with the listings package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34896/coloring-digits-with-the-listings-package/34952#34952); however, it didn't work. The digits weren't colored in the strings, but they were in the comments.

Would you be kind to suggest me a solution?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: We don't even know the syntax of your code so it will be pretty hard for us to help.

Comment: Did you read [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32174/listings-package-how-can-i-format-all-numbers/32176#32176) which is link the the one you found already? If that doesn’T help too, please add an MWE as Peter said.

Comment: Solution at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163911/21891.

Answer (score 4):

Based on “[Listings package: How can I format all numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32174/listings-package-how-can-i-format-all-numbers)” I build this code

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\textcolordummy}[2]{#2}

\lstset{
    language=TeX,
    commentstyle={\color{green}\let\textcolor\textcolordummy},
}

\lstdefinestyle{FormattedNumber}{%
    literate={0}{{\textcolor{blue}{0}}}{1}%
             {1}{{\textcolor{blue}{1}}}{1}%
             {2}{{\textcolor{blue}{2}}}{1}%
             {3}{{\textcolor{blue}{3}}}{1}%
             {4}{{\textcolor{blue}{4}}}{1}%
             {5}{{\textcolor{blue}{5}}}{1}%
             {6}{{\textcolor{blue}{6}}}{1}%
             {7}{{\textcolor{blue}{7}}}{1}%
             {8}{{\textcolor{blue}{8}}}{1}%
             {9}{{\textcolor{blue}{9}}}{1}%
             {.0}{{\textcolor{blue}{.0}}}{2}% Following is to ensure that only periods
             {.1}{{\textcolor{blue}{.1}}}{2}% followed by a digit are changed.
             {.2}{{\textcolor{blue}{.2}}}{2}%
             {.3}{{\textcolor{blue}{.3}}}{2}%
             {.4}{{\textcolor{blue}{.4}}}{2}%
             {.5}{{\textcolor{blue}{.5}}}{2}%
             {.6}{{\textcolor{blue}{.6}}}{2}%
             {.7}{{\textcolor{blue}{.7}}}{2}%
             {.8}{{\textcolor{blue}{.8}}}{2}%
             {.9}{{\textcolor{blue}{.9}}}{2}%
             ,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily,%  Optional to use this
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=FormattedNumber]
Text ... 123 4.5 % 123 comment
123
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The trick is to let the `commentstyle` disable the `\textcolor` command.

[image: result]