# lstlisting: how to color numbers in code

Tags: listings, color

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can I change the color of digits when using the listings package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23634/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-digits-when-using-the-listings-package)
>   [Listings package: How can I format all numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32174/listings-package-how-can-i-format-all-numbers)
>   [How to color digits with the listings package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40284/how-to-color-digits-with-the-listings-package)

How can you define a specific color for numbers in (Python) code using `lstlisting`?

As in this example:

[image: Picture of python syntax]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please keep in mind that it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill, I'll keep that in mind. The report is due NOW, so the MWE will be next time!