# Colors for integers in listings package

Tags: listings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the color of digits when using the listings package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23634/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-digits-when-using-the-listings-package)
>   [Listings package: How can I format all numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32174/listings-package-how-can-i-format-all-numbers)

Is it possible to have colors for integers using the listings package? I tried to define integers from 0 to 9 in `keywords` then having keywords having a different style, but it doesn't work.

Comment: See e.g. [How can I change the color of digits when using the listings package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23634) [Listings package: How can I format all numbers?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32174) or [How to color digits with the listings package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40284)