# Is there a good definition for highlighting PHP code in listings?

Tags: listings, highlighting, sourcecode

Does someone have a good definition for highlighting PHP code with the `listings` package?

Comment: According to [the manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings) a PHP definition is provided.

Comment: Sure, but there are no colours in this definition?

Comment: See the manual for details on how to change the default monochrome appearance. Note that this is not actually to do with PHP or any other language. You assign a style (with a colour if you choose) to something such as a string, and listings determines what part of the source code is a string and applies your style. Therefore you styling can apply to any language. See sections 1.3 and 2.8 of the manual for an example.

Comment: I'm aware of. My question is, does someone have a such definition, which meet the code specialities of php?

Comment: Could you clarify... Do you need help with writing the code for a style, or are you asking what colours suit PHP code? The latter is somewhat subjective.

Comment: Perhaps not too helpful, but for the former take a look at this:

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42889/colored-strings-by-listings-package/42895#42895

Ignore the literate part of that style as it's not really necessary. Maybe it'll give you a good starting point.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this post: http://martin-thoma.com/how-to-print-source-code-with-latex/ just replace java by php in the latex source

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`listings` provides lots of options to color/customize the format of the style to your likings. Of course you should choose `php` as a language.

This may be a starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,.6,0}
\definecolor{dkblue}{rgb}{0,0,.6}
\definecolor{dkyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,.8,.3}

\lstset{
  language        = php,
  basicstyle      = \small\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle    = \color{dkblue},
  stringstyle     = \color{red},
  identifierstyle = \color{dkgreen},
  commentstyle    = \color{gray},
  emph            =[1]{php},
  emphstyle       =[1]\color{black},
  emph            =[2]{if,and,or,else},
  emphstyle       =[2]\color{dkyellow}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
<?php
/* this is a stupid example */
$username = $_POST["username"];
$passwort = $_POST["passwort"];

$pass = md5($passwort);

// another comment
if($username=="Andavos" and
$pass=="fd0d9cdefd5d42dfa36c74a449aa8214")
   {
   echo "Herzlich Willkommen";
   }
else
   {
   echo "Login Fehlgeschlagen";
   }
?>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: FYI: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2414/should-we-answer-really-bad-questions I think tat this question probably qualifies. As it stands, it seems ambiguous and by answering it lowers the odds that the question will be improved to bring it up to standard.

Comment: I think it should stay now that it's here. If the question doesn't improve then the question should be closed.

Comment: I'm still hoping that it'll be updated.

Comment: Why this works when it is not included? When I include it: http://i.imgur.com/MdMrn38.png

Answer (score 7):

I found that the default parsing is somewhat weird, some functions like 'header' will be highlight, even if they are class functions, but other functions will not. All identifiers will be colored the same way, no matter if they are functions or variables. To fix the whole lstlisting highlighting I hacked the following TeXcode for use in XeTeX:

```
\newcommand{\PHPamountofcolor}{75}
\newcommand{\SourceCodeContext}{5}
%Lets define the php language colors:
\definecolor{PHP_comment_old}{HTML}{FF8000}
\colorlet{PHP_comment}{PHP_comment_old!\PHPamountofcolor!black}
\definecolor{PHP_default_old}{HTML}{000000}
\colorlet{PHP_default}{PHP_default_old!\PHPamountofcolor!black}
\definecolor{PHP_keyword_old}{HTML}{6c9c11}
\colorlet{PHP_keyword}{PHP_keyword_old!\PHPamountofcolor!black}
\definecolor{PHP_emph1_old}{HTML}{0F58A2}
\colorlet{PHP_emph1}{PHP_emph1_old!\PHPamountofcolor!black}
\definecolor{PHP_emph2_old}{HTML}{CCAA00}
\colorlet{PHP_emph2}{PHP_emph2_old!\PHPamountofcolor!black}
\definecolor{PHP_emph4_old}{HTML}{C60484}
\colorlet{PHP_emph4}{PHP_emph4_old!\PHPamountofcolor!black}
\definecolor{PHP_string_old}{HTML}{C78F0A}
\colorlet{PHP_string}{PHP_string_old!\PHPamountofcolor!black}
\definecolor{PHP_variable_old}{HTML}{C82210}%C82210
\colorlet{PHP_variable}{PHP_variable_old!\PHPamountofcolor!black}
\definecolor{PHP_number_old}{HTML}{BF1CA6}
\colorlet{PHP_number}{PHP_number_old!\PHPamountofcolor!black}
%Now we want to highlight the variables. This will be done by triggering the function \PHPhighlightvar at the start of any $ run. This function wil only highlight variables and any other identifiers will be ignored. Luckily lstlisting will only give correct identifiers so we only will have to check if the previous call was made with a $
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Courier}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{courier, textcomp}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{InString}{}% Keep track of if we are within a string
\togglefalse{InString}% Assume not initally in string

\newcommand*{\ColorIfNotInString}[1]{\iftoggle{InString}{#1}{\color{PHP_number}#1}}%
%helper

\newcommand{\PHPhighlightvar}[1]{\ifnum\theDollarFlag=1 \color{PHP_variable} \fi#1\setcounter{DollarFlag}{0}}
\newcounter{DollarFlag}


\lstset{
  language        = php,
  basicstyle      = \footnotesize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle    = \color{PHP_keyword},
  stringstyle     = \color{PHP_string!90!black}\toggletrue{InString},
  %this allows highlighting of variables:
  literate        =  {\$}{{\iftoggle{InString}{\$}{\setcounter{DollarFlag}{1}\color{PHP_variable}\$\color{PHP_default}}}}1
%    {"}{{{\ProcessQuote{"}}}}1% Disable coloring within double quotes
%    {'}{{{\ProcessQuote{'}}}}1% Disable coloring within single quote
    {0}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{0}}}}1
    {1}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{1}}}}1
    {2}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{2}}}}1
    {3}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{3}}}}1
    {4}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{4}}}}1
    {5}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{5}}}}1
    {6}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{6}}}}1
    {7}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{7}}}}1
    {8}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{8}}}}1
    {9}{{{\ColorIfNotInString{9}}}}1,
  identifierstyle = \color{PHP_default}\PHPhighlightvar,
  commentstyle    = \color{PHP_comment}\slshape,
  emph            =[1]{require_once, require, include_once, include, namespace, use, class, function, new},
  emphstyle       =[1]\color{PHP_emph1},%\bf,
  emph            =[2]{echo, empty, isset, array, instanceof},
  emphstyle       =[2]\color{PHP_emph2},%\bf,
  emph            =[3]{var, const, abstract, 
                        protected, private, public,
                        static, final, extends, implements,
                        global, if, else, foreach ,for,
                        endforeach, endif, endfor, elseif,
                        as},
  emphstyle       =[3]\color{PHP_keyword},%\bf,
  emph            =[4]{return, throw, exit, __halt_compiler, continue, break},
  emphstyle       =[4]\color{PHP_emph4},%\bf,
  breaklines      = true,
  captionpos      = b,
  rulecolor       =\color{black},
  keywords    ={__halt_compiler,    abstract,   and,    array,
                    as, break,  callable,   case,   catch,  class,
                    clone,  const,  continue,   declare,    default,
                    die,    do, echo,   else,   elseif,
                    empty,  enddeclare, endfor, endforeach, endif,
                    endswitch,  endwhile,   eval,   exit,   extends,
                    final,  finally,    for,    foreach,    function,
                    global, goto, if,   implements, include,
                    include_once,   instanceof, insteadof,
                    interface,  isset, list,    namespace,
                    new,    or, print, private, protected,  public,
                    require,    require_once, return,   static,
                    switch, throw,  trait, try, unset, use, var,
                    while,  xor,    yield,
  },
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=1,  
  numberfirstline=true,
  numberstyle=\footnotesize,
  xleftmargin=4.0ex,
  upquote=true,
  showlines=true
  }
```

Maybe this is of use for someone.
It produces something like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this; hopefully the `listings` people take notice and implement it by default.