# Print macro signature

Tags: macros, documentation

I am looking for a way to have a readable documentation of a macro signature (probably not the correct wording, but I mean the same thing as a function signature) in the source code and in the output file.

A macro signature can be printed using for example the `\cmd` command from the ltxdoc package, e.g.

```
\cmd{\myCommand[my optional argument]{my mandatory argument}}
```

which is quite readable in the source code, but prints as

```
\myCommand[my optional argument]my mandatory argument
```

in the output file. This can, of course, be changed into

```
\cmd{\myCommand[my optional argument]\{my mandatory argument\}}
```

which gets printed as

```
\myCommand[my optional argument]{my mandatory argument}
```

but the source code readability is decreased, especially if there are many mandatory arguments. There are more commands defined in ltxdoc, but they all decrease source code readability and do not solve the problem.

Is there a way to define a macro `\command` to have both a readable source code and the correct output? For a readable source code, I think

```
\command{\myCommand[my optional argument]{my mandatory argument}}
```

would be the preferred way. But all trivial approaches to write such a macro fail, as the braces are already lost, when `\command` gets called.

Is there some way to change some catcode or something locally, so that the braces do not get lost? Is there some other clever syntax to achieve readability without problematic braces? Ideally, the command would support all possible definition when using xparse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The intended usage in `ltxdoc` is

```
\cmd\myCommand\oarg{my optional argument}\marg{my mandatory argument}
```

There is also `\parg` for picture mode `()` arguments.

---

If you would rather hide the `\marg` command then perhaps:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}

\def\xcmd#1{%
\cmd#1%
\futurelet\tmp\arglook}

\def\arglook{%
\let\next\relax
\ifx[\tmp\let\next\xoarg\fi
\ifx\bgroup\tmp\let\next\xmarg\fi
\ifx(\tmp\let\next\xparg\fi
\next
}

\def\xoarg[#1]{\oarg{#1}\futurelet\tmp\arglook}
\def\xmarg#1{\marg{#1}\futurelet\tmp\arglook}
\def\xparg(#1){\parg{#1}\futurelet\tmp\arglook}

\begin{document}

\xcmd\myCommand{my optional argument}[my mandatory argument]


\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The key here is the use of `\futurelet` I could have used the LaTeX `\@ifnextchar` macro which is a wrapper around `\futurelet` with more LaTeX-like syntax and built in white space skipping, but I was afraid of the white space stripping here as there is no explicit terminator. Using `\futurelet` means that after processing each argument it only looks at the next character to see if it is `{` `[` or `(` in particular a newline stops the scan.

The key is

```
 \futurelet\tmp\arglook
```

this defines `\tmp` to be the character following `\arglook`  as if by

```
\let\tmp=[
```

*without* removing it from the token stream, So for example if after expanding `\xcmd` the next bit of the input is `{my arg}` then the token stream is

```
\futurelet\tmp\arglook{my arg}
```

so this is equivalent to

```
\let\tmp={
\arglook{myarg}
```

Note how the `{` is still there to form an argument group.

`\arglook` doesn't take an argument but it tests `\tmp` sees it is equal to `\lbrace` and so executes `\xmarg`. so in the end

```
\xmarg{myarg}
```

is executed and the group is taken as a standard argument and typeset as a mandatory argument.

If the `\futurelet` had seen a `[` then a similar sequence would have ended with executing

```
\xoarg[myarg]
```

as `\tmp` would have been `\let` to `[`.

Finally if the futurelet sees any character that is not `{` `[` or `(`  `\arglook` does nothing and the original character is still in the token stream to do whatever needs doing after the `\xcmd` header.

Comment: thanks for mentioning. These commands are well suited for a good output, but they are less well suited for a good documentation within the source code. In this question I am more interested in the latter one. The next step would be to combine both.

Comment: alternative input syntax version added

Comment: Thanks very much, the alternative input syntax was exactly what I was looking for. Could you explain how it works? I would be especially interested in the basic idea and in using the `futurelet` and why it seem to have only two arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The `ydoc-desc` package provides a `\Macro` macro for this. It takes one macro name and then scans for possible argument.

```
\Macro\myCommand[<my optional argument>]{<my mandatory argument>}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ydoc-desc}
\optionaloff % otherwise the optional arguments are displayed lighter as the normal text

\begin{document}

My macro \Macro\myCommand[<my optional arguments>]{<my mandatory argument>}
is really nice.

\end{document}
```

Here special angles are added and the argument text is in `tt` italic (if supported). This basically looks the same as with Davids answer, but by default in color:

[image: Result]

If you don't use the `< >` the argument descriptions will be in `tt` upright font and no angles are added.
You might need to add an `\relax` after it when it is followed by anything which looks like a further argument.

However, the whole `ydoc` bundle is official still in alpha stage and there is not much user documentation.

Comment: This package looks very promising, thanks for mentioning and for creating. Unfortunately, I get some error messages when using it. Do you want a bug report, given the red warning at the beginning of the documentation?

Comment: @MMM: Sorry, I confused the exact package. It's actually `ydoc-desc`. You can also simply load the `ydoc` package. I added a full example now.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Still, ydoc-desc does not seem to be created with compatibility to the docltx class in mind, as there are errors. Using the ydoc class, the errors disappear, instead there are some hyperref warnings. When ydoc leaves its alpha stage, I will probably switch to it, as it looks much better and the layout is clearer, but according to its documentation, I should wait until then.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you may of course use `\verb|\myCommand[my optional argument]{my mandatory argument}|`, but then you don't get any syntax highlighting.

You can also use the `minted` package (remember to call (pdf)LaTeX with `[pdf]latex -shell-escape your-file.tex`) and do this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

This is my command: \mint{latex}|\myCommand[my optional argument]{my mandatory argument}|.

\end{document}
```

This has a drawback, however, of typesetting `\myCommand` on a line by itself (even with skips above and below, I guess).

Comment: `listings` has `\lstinline` which can be used like `\verb` _with_ syntax highlighting.

Comment: `pythontex` has `\pygment`, which also can be used exactly like `\verb`.  It uses the same Pygments syntax highlighter that `minted` does.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, these are all very interesing ideas. I have choosen another answer, but it was a really tight win (the other solution does not need the two pipe symbols). The `listings` syntax highlighting does not seem to add much in this context (but could probably be adjusted). Minted seems to be a great package, but I wanted to avoid it in my current context, as this should all be part of a package documentation and I do not want to add complicated dependencies. I haven't looked at `\pygment`, but it will probably also lose by two characters. :-)

Comment: @MMM  true,`listings` default appearance doesn't highlight at all, but it is highly configurable ([see this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54687/5049) as one of many examples on TeX.se).

Comment: @MMM if you are just keeping track of characters,  use `\let\1\pygment` :)

Comment: @Aditya Good catch :-) Of course with \let\1\xcmd there are still two characters less. Joking aside, well named commands can save a lot of trouble. Avoiding unnecessary syntactic clutter can serve a similar purpose.