# Issues when including a tex file

Tags: listings, highlighting, input, include

I have [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54687/2144) without any issues if I use it alone. However if I call it with input or include I get this [image]

Why?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not answerable in the current form. An example of code showing the issue is necessary.

Comment: as egreg says an example is necessary however it is clear that php code has been passed directly to latex so just produces arbitrary errors, just as if latex code had been passed to php. You need to put such code in a verbatim or listings environment or some other similar environment for quoting non-latex material.

Answer (score 7):

### Reproducing the problem

Let's say, the [referenced answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54687/16967) is in file `answer.tex`. Then a minimal main document would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\input{answer}
\end{document}
```

That generates tons of errors. let's ignore them with `\batchmode` (or pressing `q` at the first error message). The result is:

> [image: Problem]

### Analysis and hints

What happened, you have tried to input a *complete* LaTeX document inside the body of another. This is not allowed, already the first error messages say this:

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \documentclass
                  {article}
```

The PDF output (image above) is the result of LaTeX's/TeX's error recovery –
put a frame around, then you can call it "Modern Art". :-)

A preamble (the stuff before `\begin{document}`) cannot be called after `\begin{document}`. But you can **merge** the two preambles. For example, if you need package `listings` for the second document, but the first document has not loaded it, then add

```
\usepackage{listings}
```

to the preamble of the main document.
The same applies to the color definitions (`\definecolor` lines) and the settings (`\lstset`) for package `listings`. Put them into the preamble of the main document.

Then in the *body* (between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`
you can put the body or parts of it of the second document via copy-paste, `\input` or `\include`. The latter can only be used for parts of the document that start and ends at page boundaries (e.g. chapters) and cannot be nested.

A scheme for the new main document would be:

1. Old preamble with `\documentclass` and packages.
2. Additional packages (e.g. `\usepackage{listings}`)
3. Additional settings (e.g. color definitions, `\lstset`)
4. `\begin{document}`
5. ...
6. Variant 1: `\begin{lstlistings}...\end{lstlistings}` with the PHP code inbetween.
7. Variant 2: The PHP code can be put into a file and included via
    via `\lstinputlisting` (see the documentation of `listings`)
8. Variant 3: The body of the answer document (between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and excluding these markers) can be put into a file that is
   included via `\input`.
9. (Variant 4: `\include` does not make sense here.)
10. ...
11. `\end{document}`

I hope, it helps a little or specify, what you want to achieve.

Comment: This is the [old](https://gist.github.com/ilhanyumer/52f4a239ea446d1365e3#file-old-tex) latex code. And this is the [new](https://gist.github.com/ilhanyumer/52f4a239ea446d1365e3#file-new-tex) latex code. And this is the [diff](https://gist.github.com/ilhanyumer/52f4a239ea446d1365e3/revisions), the top one. It is a bit okay now but not fully okay http://i.imgur.com/Dmwz03j.png I have put the latex code to different parts in the latex document but it gives same result or worse.

Comment: Please learn to make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I would but http://ii2.metu.edu.tr/sites/ii2.metu.edu.tr/files/thesis-latex-template.zip is too much complicated. I'll try other methods.

Comment: The issue is caused by [metu.cls](https://gist.github.com/ilhanyumer/e88d83b901edcb072f7b)