# Listing package only outputs black colored source code even though the language parameter is specified

Tags: listings, color

The problem is pretty much in the title.

With this code:

```
\documentclass{report}    
\usepackage{listings}    
\begin{document}  
\lstset{language=Python}
\begin{lstlisting}
def some_function(parameter):
    a_random_number = parameter - 10
    print "some random string" + str(a_random_number)

if __name__ == '__main__'
    print 'Hello Latex Listings package'
    some_function(20)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I am getting no color whatsoever, just some bolded keywords:

[image]

Any idea why this might be and how to fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: That's the default appearance. But `listings` provides many options for customization, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54687/5049 for an example

Comment: That's the default style for Python, as defined in `lstdrvrs.dtx` (a file that ships with the `listings` package). You can override aspects of that style (colour, etc.) by passing new values to keys such as `keywordstyle`, `commentstyle` and `stringstyle`. See the [documentation](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).

Comment: You might want to look into the [minted package](https://code.google.com/p/minted/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have correctly mentioned in the comments, you are using default behavior. To customize it, you can do something like this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\geometry{a4paper}

\begin{document}

This is a sample file:

    \lstset{
    language=python,
    tabsize=3,
    %frame=lines,
    caption=Test,
    label=code:sample,
    frame=shadowbox,
    rulesepcolor=\color{gray},
    xleftmargin=20pt,
    framexleftmargin=15pt,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bf,
    commentstyle=\color{OliveGreen},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    numbersep=5pt,
    breaklines=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    emph={str},emphstyle={\color{magenta}}}
    %\lstinputlisting{simple.py}
    \begin{lstlisting}
    def some_function(parameter):
        a_random_number = parameter - 10
        print "some random string" + str(a_random_number)
    # And a random comment!
    if __name__ == '__main__'
        print 'Hello Latex Listings package'
        some_function(20)
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

You can add your python script either by using `\begin{lstlisting}` or saving it in an external file and then later adding it by `\lstinputlisting{simple.py}`. I personally prefer external files to keep the source cleaner. Moreover, you can add extra keywords as I have done for `str` function.

[image]