# Code highlighting for imported source files

Tags: verbatim, highlighting, sourcecode

I have several source code files that I would like to include in my document.

I know that I can use `verbatiminput` to get the lines from the file, and use `lstlisting` to highlight the code, but I cannot seem to use them both together. What I have in mind is something like:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
    \lstset{language=Java}
    \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
        \verbatiminput{filename.java}
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

But naturally this does not work, as the `\verbatiminput{filename.java}` will not get executed inside of the `lstlisting`.

Comment: don't use verbatiminput, listings has commands for including files, eg `\lstinputlisting` use instead of the `lstlisting` env, which is for code within the document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that's definitely an answer.

Comment: @masu ah I hadn't actually tested it I just stole the words from an answer earlier today: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147758/1090

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`listings` offers these commands:

1. `\lstinline` -- for code snippets (similar to `\verb` but can highlight code)
2. `\lstlisting`  -- Environment where you can put your code in display mode.
3. `\lstinputlisting` -- for including `standalone` files.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{filename.java}
  public class HelloWorld {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello, World");
   }
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
    \lstset{language=Java}
    This is where a code snippet: \lstinline!public static HelloWorld {! comes

    And here is the displayed code:

    \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
          public class HelloWorld {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello, World");
   }
}
    \end{lstlisting}

    And now to include an external source file:
    \lstinputlisting[frame=single]{filename.java}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For your case, use `\lstinputlisting`