# Quotation mark in \lstinputlisting becomes white

Tags: listings, color

How can I fix this issue with everything inside and including the "quotation mark" itself becomes white, in my case invisible due to the white background.

Thanks in advance.

I almost forgot that im using following `\lstset`:

```
\lstset{
        basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, % Standardschrift
        %numbers=left,               % Ort der Zeilennummern
        numberstyle=\tiny,          % Stil der Zeilennummern
        %stepnumber=2,               % Abstand zwischen den Zeilennummern
        numbersep=5pt,              % Abstand der Nummern zum Text
        tabsize=2,                  % Groesse von Tabs
        extendedchars=true,         %
        breaklines=true,            % Zeilen werden Umgebrochen
        keywordstyle=\color{red},
        frame=b,         
%        keywordstyle=[1]\textbf,    % Stil der Keywords
%        keywordstyle=[2]\textbf,    %
%        keywordstyle=[3]\textbf,    %
%        keywordstyle=[4]\textbf,   \sqrt{\sqrt{}} %
        stringstyle=\color{white}\ttfamily, % Farbe der String
        showspaces=false,           % Leerzeichen anzeigen ?
        showtabs=false,             % Tabs anzeigen ?
        xleftmargin=17pt,
        framexleftmargin=17pt,
        framexrightmargin=5pt,
        framexbottommargin=4pt,
        %backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
        showstringspaces=false,      % Leerzeichen in Strings anzeigen ?  
        inputencoding=utf8,
          literate={å}{{\aa}}1
                        {æ}{{\ae}}1
                         {ø}{{\o}}1      
}

\lstloadlanguages{% Check Dokumentation for further languages ...
        %[Visual]Basic
        %Pascal
        C,
        %C++
        %XML
        %HTML
        Java
}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox[cmyk]{0.43, 0.35, 0.35,0.01}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\hspace{15pt}#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white, singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={bf,footnotesize}}
```

Comment: Please, add a minimal example of code

Comment: Here you’ll find more information about [minimal working examples (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: There's a missing comma after `showstringspaces=false`. However also an example of the failing code is necessary.

Comment: @egreg, thanks for noticing that typo, i have corrected it. I will look into minimal working example.

Comment: Related post: [Colored strings by `listings` package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42889/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious problem here is that you're setting your strings to be `\color{white}\ttfamily`, and strings are initiated in a listing via single or double quotes, depending on the language. If you want your strings to show, use `\color{black}\ttfamily` (or another colour other than `white`).

The [`listings` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) contains some minimal examples that illustrate the default behaviour of typesetting strings (for example, the inclusion of a squat-U - or `\textvisiblespace` - as a visible space character). As such, you modify string-specific behaviour. See **Strings** (p 44) of **4.18 Language Definitions**.