# How can I make listings look like minted?

Tags: listings, highlighting, minted, code

Up until now I used the `listings` package for my code-listings. Today, I tried `minted` and I'm pleased with the default look. Since I'd have a lot to do to switch from `listings` to `minted` at this stage of my thesis, I'd like to mimic the look.

In the following picture, you see the same source-code in `listingz` and `minted`.
Could you help me identify the appropriate `listings` settings to make the left example look like the right one? I can figure out the colours myself, but the rest (spacing, font, etc.) puzzles me.

[image]

There are my styling-settings for listing:

```
% javascript code listing
\newcommand{\inputjscode}[2][]{{%
    \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{JavaScript Code}%
    \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{\oldaddcontentsline{los}{##2}{##3\enskip(\lstlistingname)}}%
        \lstset{
            tabsize=2,
            lineskip=-1pt,
            rulecolor=,
            basicstyle=\footnotesize,
            columns=fullflexible,
            upquote=true,
            aboveskip={1.3\baselineskip},
            columns=fixed,
            showstringspaces=false,
            extendedchars=true,
            breaklines=false,
            prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
            escapechar=@,
            frame=single,
            showtabs=false,
            showspaces=false,
            showstringspaces=false,
            identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
            keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{1.0,0,0},
            keywordstyle=[1]\color[rgb]{0,0,0.75},
            keywordstyle=[2]\color[rgb]{0.5,0.0,0.0},
            keywordstyle=[3]\color[rgb]{0.127,0.427,0.514},
            keywordstyle=[4]\color[rgb]{0.4,0.4,0.4},
            commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133},
            stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.639,0.082,0.082},
        }
    \lstinputlisting[
    numbers=left, 
    frame=single, 
    stepnumber=1, 
    inputencoding=latin1, 
    language=JavaScript, 
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    #1]{#2}%
}}
```

Comment: Two suggestions: Add `basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize` to switch to monowidth font in `lstlisting`.  `commentstyle=\itshape` italicizes the comments.

Comment: that improved it already a lot. As well as `numberstyle=\tiny`

Comment: Check also the value of that `columns` key in your code.  You have it twice and I think at the end of the day, you want `columns=flexible`.

Comment: Looks like the syntax (that the styles are applied according to) are the same. The only problem is to figure out the settings on the right and set up your listings. For instance, besides what ArashEsbati said, comments are italic on the right.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to replicate it pretty closely using `listings`.[image]

Ultimately, the part that made it tricky is that you have redundant commands in your `\lstset` (and presumably also where you defined keywords for Javascript): for example, the colors you provided for different keyword styles were overridden by others that were already defined.

I started with a `listings` language definition for Javascript, which I got from [this TeX.sx post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89576/55879); however, we'll be modifying the colors, so I removed the definitions we won't use.

```
\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
  keywords={typeof, new, true, false, catch, function, return, null, catch, switch, var, if, in, while, do, else, case, break},
  ndkeywords={class, export, boolean, throw, implements, import, this},
  sensitive=false,
  comment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"
}
```

Then, we define the style, which comes from setting the colors (and italics for comments) in `keywordstyle`, `commentstyle`, etc., along with a few spacing adjustments. I always alphabetize my `\lstset` call so that I can quickly figure out whether I've already added a command rather than duplicating it.

```
\lstset{
    aboveskip={1.3\baselineskip},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily\linespread{4},
    breaklines=false,
    columns=flexible,
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.127,0.427,0.514}\ttfamily\itshape,
    escapechar=@,
    extendedchars=true,
    frame=single,
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    inputencoding=latin1,
    keywordstyle=\color[HTML]{228B22}\bfseries,
    language=JavaScript,
    ndkeywordstyle=\color[HTML]{228B22}\bfseries,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
    showstringspaces=false,
    stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.639,0.082,0.082}\ttfamily,
    upquote=true
}
```

Finally, `minted` highlights the numbers in gray. [This TeX.sx answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42895/55879) shows us how to do it in `listings`:

```
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{.4,.4,.4}
\lstset{literate=%
   *{0}{{{\color{darkgray}0}}}1
    {1}{{{\color{darkgray}1}}}1
    {2}{{{\color{darkgray}2}}}1
%   ... and so on
    {9}{{{\color{darkgray}9}}}1
}
```

Here's my whole working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{.4,.4,.4}

\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
  keywords={typeof, new, true, false, catch, function, return, null, catch, switch, var, if, in, while, do, else, case, break},
  ndkeywords={class, export, boolean, throw, implements, import, this},
  sensitive=false,
  comment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"
}

\lstset{
    aboveskip={1.3\baselineskip},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily\linespread{4},
    breaklines=false,
    columns=flexible,
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.127,0.427,0.514}\ttfamily\itshape,
    escapechar=@,
    extendedchars=true,
    frame=single,
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    inputencoding=latin1,
    keywordstyle=\color[HTML]{228B22}\bfseries,
    language=JavaScript,
    ndkeywordstyle=\color[HTML]{228B22}\bfseries,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
    stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.639,0.082,0.082}\ttfamily,
    upquote=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
}

\lstset{literate=%
   *{0}{{{\color{darkgray}0}}}1
    {1}{{{\color{darkgray}1}}}1
    {2}{{{\color{darkgray}2}}}1
    {3}{{{\color{darkgray}3}}}1
    {4}{{{\color{darkgray}4}}}1
    {5}{{{\color{darkgray}5}}}1
    {6}{{{\color{darkgray}6}}}1
    {7}{{{\color{darkgray}7}}}1
    {8}{{{\color{darkgray}8}}}1
    {9}{{{\color{darkgray}9}}}1
} 

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{filename.js}
\end{document}
```