# Work-around for minted code highlighting in arXiv?

Tags: minted, arxiv

I am currently trying to submit my bachelors thesis to arXiv. However, it does not work:

```
(/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty))

Package ifplatform Warning: 
shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

))

! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
... 

l.50 \setcapindent
{0pt}
? 
! Emergency stop.
... 

l.50 \setcapindent
{0pt}
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on thesis.log.
```

Is there a work-around for this error?

For example, could I create an intermediate file so that arXiv does not have to execute minted?

Comment: Consider using the [`listings`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf) package instead of `minted`; it also highlights source code (and can be tweaked to look very similar to `minted`), but does not require shell-escape.

Comment: @ArunDebray Could you post an example where it looks similar to minted?

Comment: @ArunDebray Never mind, I've just found http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117531/5645 which looks close enough. I think I let this question open, though, as other people might have the same problem and not the possibility to switch to listings as easily as I could.

Comment: just in case you still need/want it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/272133/55879. Best of luck!

Comment: Here's another workaround: http://www.insectnation.org/blog/pygmentizing-code-for-latex.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You know you really should provide an MWE:-)

So here's one:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

zzz

\begin{minted}{html}
<!DOCTYPE html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <ol>
  <li class="z">z
    <li>zzzz</li>
    <li>something <b>bold</b></li>
  </ol>
  <p><a href="somewhere.html">aaa</a></p>
 </body>
</html>
\end{minted}


\end{document
```

which makes

[image]

Now all the formatting is cached in a `_minted-something` directory of the current file.

When minted uses that cache it doesn't use `pygmentize` so wouldn't need shell escape, except that it does shell escape for checking and cleaning up.
It could have an option to just use the cache but as it doesn't, help it a bit.

The cache has three files:

```
$ ls _minted-gg496/
9CEDBF3C3E0F3958DE3150F596B294B8E453E7F2043D40FA47ECCB2444F29644.pygtex
default.pygstyle
default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle
```

copy the two `*.pygstyle` files into the preamble, and the `*.pygtex` file (the one with the long name) where you want your listing, and use the `[draft]` option so `minted` does not try to shell-escape:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[draft]{minted}


\makeatletter
\def\PYGdefault@reset{\let\PYGdefault@it=\relax \let\PYGdefault@bf=\relax%
    \let\PYGdefault@ul=\relax \let\PYGdefault@tc=\relax%
    \let\PYGdefault@bc=\relax \let\PYGdefault@ff=\relax}
\def\PYGdefault@tok#1{\csname PYGdefault@tok@#1\endcsname}
\def\PYGdefault@toks#1+{\ifx\relax#1\empty\else%
    \PYGdefault@tok{#1}\expandafter\PYGdefault@toks\fi}
\def\PYGdefault@do#1{\PYGdefault@bc{\PYGdefault@tc{\PYGdefault@ul{%
    \PYGdefault@it{\PYGdefault@bf{\PYGdefault@ff{#1}}}}}}}
\def\PYGdefault#1#2{\PYGdefault@reset\PYGdefault@toks#1+\relax+\PYGdefault@do{#2}}

\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@gd\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@gu\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@bf=\textbf\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.50,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@gt\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.27,0.87}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@gs\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@bf=\textbf}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@gr\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@cm\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@it=\textit\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@vg\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@m\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@mh\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@go\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.53,0.53}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@ge\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@it=\textit}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@vc\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@il\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@cs\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@it=\textit\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@cp\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.74,0.48,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@gi\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.63,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@gh\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@bf=\textbf\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@ni\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@bf=\textbf\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.60,0.60,0.60}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@nl\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.63,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@nn\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@bf=\textbf\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@no\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@na\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.49,0.56,0.16}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@nb\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@nc\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@bf=\textbf\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@nd\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.67,0.13,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@ne\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@bf=\textbf\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.82,0.25,0.23}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@nf\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@si\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@bf=\textbf\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@s2\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@vi\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@nt\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@bf=\textbf\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@nv\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@s1\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@sh\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@sc\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@sx\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@bp\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@c1\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@it=\textit\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@kc\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@bf=\textbf\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@c\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@it=\textit\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@mf\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@err\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@bc##1{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fcolorbox[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{1,1,1}{\strut ##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@kd\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@bf=\textbf\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@ss\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@sr\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@mo\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@kn\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@bf=\textbf\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@mi\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@gp\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@bf=\textbf\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@o\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@kr\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@bf=\textbf\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@s\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@kp\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@w\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.73,0.73}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@kt\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.00,0.25}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@ow\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@bf=\textbf\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.67,0.13,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@sb\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@k\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@bf=\textbf\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@se\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@bf=\textbf\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@sd\endcsname{\let\PYGdefault@it=\textit\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}

\def\PYGdefaultZbs{\char`\\}
\def\PYGdefaultZus{\char`\_}
\def\PYGdefaultZob{\char`\{}
\def\PYGdefaultZcb{\char`\}}
\def\PYGdefaultZca{\char`\^}
\def\PYGdefaultZam{\char`\&}
\def\PYGdefaultZlt{\char`\<}
\def\PYGdefaultZgt{\char`\>}
\def\PYGdefaultZsh{\char`\#}
\def\PYGdefaultZpc{\char`\%}
\def\PYGdefaultZdl{\char`\$}
\def\PYGdefaultZhy{\char`\-}
\def\PYGdefaultZsq{\char`\'}
\def\PYGdefaultZdq{\char`\"}
\def\PYGdefaultZti{\char`\~}
% for compatibility with earlier versions
\def\PYGdefaultZat{@}
\def\PYGdefaultZlb{[}
\def\PYGdefaultZrb{]}
\makeatother


\makeatletter
\def\PYG@reset{\let\PYG@it=\relax \let\PYG@bf=\relax%
    \let\PYG@ul=\relax \let\PYG@tc=\relax%
    \let\PYG@bc=\relax \let\PYG@ff=\relax}
\def\PYG@tok#1{\csname PYG@tok@#1\endcsname}
\def\PYG@toks#1+{\ifx\relax#1\empty\else%
    \PYG@tok{#1}\expandafter\PYG@toks\fi}
\def\PYG@do#1{\PYG@bc{\PYG@tc{\PYG@ul{%
    \PYG@it{\PYG@bf{\PYG@ff{#1}}}}}}}
\def\PYG#1#2{\PYG@reset\PYG@toks#1+\relax+\PYG@do{#2}}

\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@gd\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@gu\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.50,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@gt\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.27,0.87}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@gs\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@gr\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@cm\endcsname{\let\PYG@it=\textit\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@vg\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@m\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@mh\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@go\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.53,0.53}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@ge\endcsname{\let\PYG@it=\textit}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@vc\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@il\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@cs\endcsname{\let\PYG@it=\textit\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@cp\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.74,0.48,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@gi\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.63,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@gh\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@ni\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.60,0.60,0.60}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@nl\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.63,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@nn\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@no\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@na\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.49,0.56,0.16}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@nb\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@nc\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@nd\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.67,0.13,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@ne\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.82,0.25,0.23}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@nf\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@si\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@s2\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@vi\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@nt\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@nv\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@s1\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@sh\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@sc\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@sx\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@bp\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@c1\endcsname{\let\PYG@it=\textit\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@kc\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@c\endcsname{\let\PYG@it=\textit\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@mf\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@err\endcsname{\def\PYG@bc##1{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fcolorbox[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{1,1,1}{\strut ##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@kd\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@ss\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@sr\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@mo\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@kn\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@mi\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@gp\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@o\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@kr\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@s\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@kp\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@w\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.73,0.73}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@kt\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.00,0.25}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@ow\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.67,0.13,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@sb\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@k\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@se\endcsname{\let\PYG@bf=\textbf\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@sd\endcsname{\let\PYG@it=\textit\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}

\def\PYGZbs{\char`\\}
\def\PYGZus{\char`\_}
\def\PYGZob{\char`\{}
\def\PYGZcb{\char`\}}
\def\PYGZca{\char`\^}
\def\PYGZam{\char`\&}
\def\PYGZlt{\char`\<}
\def\PYGZgt{\char`\>}
\def\PYGZsh{\char`\#}
\def\PYGZpc{\char`\%}
\def\PYGZdl{\char`\$}
\def\PYGZhy{\char`\-}
\def\PYGZsq{\char`\'}
\def\PYGZdq{\char`\"}
\def\PYGZti{\char`\~}
% for compatibility with earlier versions
\def\PYGZat{@}
\def\PYGZlb{[}
\def\PYGZrb{]}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

zzz

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PYG{c+cp}{\PYGZlt{}!DOCTYPE html}
\PYG{c+cp}{\PYGZlt{}html\PYGZgt{}}
 \PYG{n+nt}{\PYGZlt{}head\PYGZgt{}}
 \PYG{n+nt}{\PYGZlt{}/head\PYGZgt{}}
 \PYG{n+nt}{\PYGZlt{}body\PYGZgt{}}
 \PYG{n+nt}{\PYGZlt{}ol\PYGZgt{}}
  \PYG{n+nt}{\PYGZlt{}li} \PYG{n+na}{class=}\PYG{l+s}{\PYGZdq{}z\PYGZdq{}}\PYG{n+nt}{\PYGZgt{}}z
    \PYG{n+nt}{\PYGZlt{}li\PYGZgt{}}zzzz\PYG{n+nt}{\PYGZlt{}/li\PYGZgt{}}
    \PYG{n+nt}{\PYGZlt{}li\PYGZgt{}}something \PYG{n+nt}{\PYGZlt{}b\PYGZgt{}}bold\PYG{n+nt}{\PYGZlt{}/b\PYGZgt{}\PYGZlt{}/li\PYGZgt{}}
  \PYG{n+nt}{\PYGZlt{}/ol\PYGZgt{}}
  \PYG{n+nt}{\PYGZlt{}p\PYGZgt{}\PYGZlt{}a} \PYG{n+na}{href=}\PYG{l+s}{\PYGZdq{}somewhere.html\PYGZdq{}}\PYG{n+nt}{\PYGZgt{}}aaa\PYG{n+nt}{\PYGZlt{}/a\PYGZgt{}\PYGZlt{}/p\PYGZgt{}}
 \PYG{n+nt}{\PYGZlt{}/body\PYGZgt{}}
\PYG{n+nt}{\PYGZlt{}/html\PYGZgt{}}
\end{Verbatim}


\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

---

**Update:** the next version of `minted` will have options so that the edits described here will be done automatically just adding a package option will be sufficient, see

https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/113#issuecomment-223451550

Comment: These files could be `\input`ed in the preamble and where the code should appear, unless I am missing something?

Comment: Also, the `draft` mode works with the newer versions of `minted`, but not for the outdated one on ArXiv (will have to package [`minted.sty`](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/blob/a75a4a184cefb1e332a234cacefcc9ccefeced9f/source/minted.sty) together with the document source itself).

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis yes you could of course input them, I added a feature request to minted so it does all this automatically (just re-use an existing generated file without needing shell escape https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/113

Comment: Thanks, also for reporting the issue, actually I came across it yesterday as I was searching.

Answer (score 25):

As already [pointed out by David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280685/92943), minted provides a built-in workaround for environments that don't support `-shell-escape`/Pyhton/Pygments.

As of minted version [2.2](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/releases/tag/v2.2), you can use the package options `finalizecache` and `frozencache`:

> These allow the cache to be prepared for (`finalizecache`) and then used (`frozencache`) […] Note that this only works if minted content does not need to be modified, and if no settings that depend on Pygments or Python need to be changed […]

That is, in a first step compile the document using `finalizecache`, then switch to `frozencache`. Afterwards, you can simply include the `_minted-${project-name}` folder in the arXiv upload and everything should be fine.

Comment: I am an Overleaf user and this worked for me, even using `tcolorbox`. Step one: compile with `\usepackage[finalizecache,cachedir=.]{minted}`. Step two: go to logs and output files > other logs and files and download everything with pyg. Step three: change `finalizecache` to `frozencache` and upload the tex+all those pyg files to arXiv. `Success!`

Comment: In my case, I also needed to clear cache first before @rhombidodecahedron's steps, and it worked!

Answer (score 10):

As of Aug 10th, 2020. I have to use `\usepackage[finalizecache,cachedir=.]{minted}` while I work on the writing. When the document is finalized, compile and download everything with pyg, change the line to `\usepackage[frozencache,cachedir=.]{minted}`, and include the `pyg` files in the arXiv upload.

PS: If you use Overleaf, then you can find these folders by clicking the "Logs and output files" button next to compile button.

Comment: it's explicitely said on arxiv to not use a hidden directory for caching: https://arxiv.org/help/faq/mistakes#minted

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I first compiled using `\usepackage[finalizecache,cachedir=minted-cache]{minted}` and then change to   `\usepackage[frozencache,cachedir=minted-cache]{minted}` and then I upload it to the Arxiv. But still it wasn't compiling on Arxiv. So included `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gpoore/minted/master/source/minted.sty` inside my archive and it went successfully through the compilation.

Comment: This is the current recommended workaround when this occurs after following the above solutions. The reason for this is that arXiv doesn't update the tex tree more than once every couple of years (currently planning to do so soon!), so packages that have been updated between upgrades would need to be included in your source.

Comment: Confirm. I needed that as well (still) in 14.04.2023

Comment: I had the same issue. Moreover, I also included `minted1.sty`. Moreover, I also had an error saying "! LaTeX Error: Environment Verbatim undefined." I corrected that by including `fvextra.sty` from my installation.

Comment: This is the answer that still works as of Dec 29, 2023.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, but none of the above answers worked. Finally, I had to specify the option `cachedir=.` in order to generate the cache in the same directory than the `tex` file.

After that, it compiled on arxiv.