# arXiv messes up minted float positioning

Tags: minted, arxiv

When I try to upload [my thesis](https://bitbucket.org/beatngu13/master-thesis/) on arXiv, I get many warnings like "Float too large for page […]" or "[…] float specifier changed to […]". I recognized that almost every minted float is wrongly positioned, which causes other floats (e.g. images) to be mispositioned as well.

In order to use minted on arXiv, I followed [these instructions](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/113#issuecomment-223451550) (found via [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280590/work-around-for-minted-code-highlighting-in-arxiv)). That is, I first compile locally with the minted option `finalizecache` enabled. Afterwards, I put the entire `_minted-${project-name}` folder into the archive that gets uploaded on arXiv and change the minted option to `frozencache` (which looks good on my machine).

Is there anything I can do to fix the positioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that when I downgrade my TeX Live version to 2016 (the one arXiv uses), I can reproduce the behavior. minted [v2.5](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/releases/tag/v2.5) introduced the following change:

> The default placement for the `listing` float is now `tbp` instead of `h`,
>   to parallel `figure` and `table` and also avoid warnings caused by `h`
>   ([#165](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/165)).

When I set this in the preamble:

```
\SetupFloatingEnvironment{listing}{placement=tbp}
```

The minted floats are positioned as expected.