# Package minted Error: Missing style definition for with frozencache when submitting to arxiv

Tags: minted, arxiv

I am following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280590/work-around-for-minted-code-highlighting-in-arxiv) to submit a latex file with minted code highlighting to arxiv.
I first compile locally with:

```
\usepackage[finalizecache,cachedir=minted-cache]{minted}
```

Then I change the tex file to:

```
\usepackage[frozencache,cachedir=minted-cache]{minted}
```

When submitting to arxiv in addition to submitting the minted-cache folder.
I then get during compilation on the arxiv servers:

```
! Package minted Error: Missing style definition for with frozencache.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...

l.583 \end{minted}
```

Any lead on what I could try to fix it ?

Comment: Please send me support request to arXiv through our [support portal](http://arxiv.org/support/general_help) with the submit-id and I'll look at your issue on Monday when I'm back in the office.

Comment: Todd'solution worked for me! I took the `sty` files directly from https://github.com/gpoore/minted/blob/master/source/minted.sty

Comment: @Jake, since Todd's solution worked for me as well no need for support !

Comment: As @Todd said it does hint at arxiv using an older minted version.

Comment: Note that it works with nested tex files as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get around this by copying `minted.sty` and `minted1.sty` from my local TeXLive distribution into the paper directory.  I think the issue is that arXiv is using an older minted version than the one I built my cache with.

Comment: Thank you @Todd Gamblin it works very well !