# ArXiv upload failed on \documentclass [acmsmall]{acmart}

Tags: document-classes, arxiv, acmart

I am a Latex and ArXiv newbie.  I tried to upload a .tex file that worked in Overleaf, and got the following error log:

```
[verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: *** Using TeX Live 2020 ***
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]: <Updating_Views.tex> is of type 'LATEX2e'.
[verbose]: <spbasic.bst> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <spmpsci.bst> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <spphys.bst> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <svglov3.clo> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <svjour3.cls> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'Updating_Views.tex'
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running latex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4554558/ && latex 'Updating_Views.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=latex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Updating_Views.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-09-06>
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/acmart/acmart.cls
Document Class: acmart 2020/09/13 v1.73 Typesetting articles for the Associatio
n for Computing Machinery
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pdftex.def)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/totpages/totpages.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/atveryend/atveryend.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty))))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperxmp/hyperxmp.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifmtarg/ifmtarg.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/ifdraft.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/geometry.cfg
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ncctools/manyfoot.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ncctools/nccfoots.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftex/glyphtounicode.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cmap/cmap.sty

Package cmap Warning: pdftex in DVI mode - exiting.

) (/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/newtxmath.sty
`newtxmath' v1.630, 2020/09/19 Math macros based originally on txfonts (msharpe
) (/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/centernot.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kastrup/binhex.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/libertine.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/LinLibertine_I.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/inconsolata/zi4.sty
`inconsolata-zi4' v1.12, 2019/05/17 Text macros for Inconsolata (msharpe))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption-ams-smf.sto)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/comment/comment.sty
Excluding comment 'comment') Excluding comment 'CCSXML'
(/texlive/2020/texmf-arxiv/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
Special comment 'acks'
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/T1LinuxLibertineT-TLF.fd))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvips.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-postscript.
def)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)

(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.c
ode.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex
)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmet
ics.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.
tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.t
ex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.cod
e.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.t
ex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
)) (/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibr
arytopaths.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tikz-cd/tikzlibrarycd.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibr
arymatrix.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibr
aryquotes.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.
tex))) (/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted/minted.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fvextra/fvextra.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/catchfile/catchfile.sty)

Package ifplatform Warning:
shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

) (/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty))

! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...

l.53

?
! Emergency stop.
...

l.53

No pages of output.
Transcript written on Updating_Views.log.

[verbose]: latex 'Updating_Views.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running pdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4554558/ && pdflatex 'Updating_Views.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Updating_Views.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-09-06>
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/acmart/acmart.cls
Document Class: acmart 2020/09/13 v1.73 Typesetting articles for the Associatio
n for Computing Machinery
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pdftex.def)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/totpages/totpages.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/atveryend/atveryend.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperxmp/hyperxmp.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifmtarg/ifmtarg.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/ifdraft.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/geometry.cfg
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ncctools/manyfoot.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ncctools/nccfoots.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftex/glyphtounicode.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cmap/cmap.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty<<t1.cmap>>)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/newtxmath.sty
`newtxmath' v1.630, 2020/09/19 Math macros based originally on txfonts (msharpe
) (/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/centernot.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kastrup/binhex.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/libertine.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/LinLibertine_I.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/inconsolata/zi4.sty
`inconsolata-zi4' v1.12, 2019/05/17 Text macros for Inconsolata (msharpe))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption-ams-smf.sto)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/comment/comment.sty
Excluding comment 'comment') Excluding comment 'CCSXML'
(/texlive/2020/texmf-arxiv/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
Special comment 'acks'
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/T1LinuxLibertineT-TLF.fd))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)

(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.c
ode.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex
)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmet
ics.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.
tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.t
ex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.cod
e.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.t
ex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
)) (/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibr
arytopaths.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tikz-cd/tikzlibrarycd.code.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibr
arymatrix.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibr
aryquotes.code.tex)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.
tex))) (/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted/minted.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fvextra/fvextra.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/catchfile/catchfile.sty)

Package ifplatform Warning:
shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

) (/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty))

! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...

l.53

?
! Emergency stop.
...

l.53

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on Updating_Views.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'Updating_Views.tex' failed.
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4554558/ && tex 'Updating_Views.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=tex)
(./Updating_Views.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[acmsmall]{acmart}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
[acmsmall]{acmart}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on Updating_Views.log.

[verbose]: tex 'Updating_Views.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'Updating_Views.tex'
[error]: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.
*** AutoTeX ABORTING ***

[verbose]: AutoTeX returned error: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.

[verbose]: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[verbose]: Error running AutoTeX process:
```

Comment: You are using `minted` package which requires `-shell-escape`, which might not be supported by arXiv (I am not sure about what arXiv does). As an alternative, you can use `listings` package.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/414781/36296

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry Thank you for your help.  I switched from the Minted to the Listings package.  I had only one six-line SQL statement, so it was easy.