End of 2024 version of "How to submit tex minted package to arxiv"
I have a file that I use minted with, in particular for python, in overleaf. Submitting to ArXiV with this is already a genuine mess, but after some trial and error I followed this guide:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/725077/21309
It didn't fully work, but I could get further by adding minted.sty itself to the files:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/659452/21309
And I also needed to add fvextra.sty:
Work-around for minted code highlighting in arXiv?
But alas! This is not anymore enough, since 2024/10/16, apparently. At this stage, I get the error:
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>

l.33 \RequirePackage{latex2pydata}[2024/10/16]
^^M
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.

Which leads to:
! Package minted Error: Missing definition for highlighting style "default" (mi
nted executable is unavailable or disabled); attempting to substitute fallback
style.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...

l.233 \end{minted}

?
! Emergency stop.
...

l.233 \end{minted}

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Which is the error I was getting when minted.sty (and minted1.sty) were not added to the files.
I am stuck here, any advice?

it is a bit unclear where you get the error. If it is in arxiv I would suggest to ask their support https://info.arxiv.org/help/contact.html#contacting-arxiv

@UlrikeFischer it is in arxiv, and I have asked them too, thanks for the suggestion! If I do get a reliable answer, I'll post it here, but given that all the previous times (e.g. linked comments) its been the community that found solutions, I decided it was a good idea to ask here anyway.

Something that is not mentioned in the linked question is the even more manual solution of compiling the minted snippets locally to standalone pdf files and including those files with \includegraphics in your arXiv submission (or pdfpages if the code spans more than one page).

ArXiv Answer is basically "sorry you can't do this anymore".
