# How to highlight all words of the form [0-9][A-Za-z0-9]* immediately following an equal sign?

Tags: listings, color

I am using the Latex Listings package to include code in a document. I need to implemented syntax highlighting similar to what you see in a standard IDE.

I've been able to assign colors to comments, keywords, and strings, but I am having some trouble figuring out how to color the numbers properly.

Here's an example of how it should look:

[image: required output]

As you can see, anytime a word after the equals sign starts with a digit, all following characters until (but not including) the next semicolon or space are colored. When a word starts with a digit, all characters in the word should be colored, even if they are not digits. Otherwise, none of the digits are colored.

As of right now, I cannot think of a case where a word before the equals sign would start with a digit, so it will probably be acceptable to find a solution that colors all words starting with a digit.

In this case, digits are: 0-9.

Here's an MWE in Latex, but as you can see it doesn't have any coloring for the numbers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{Code}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{Keywords}{rgb}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{Strings}{rgb}{255,0,255}
\definecolor{Comments}{rgb}{0,0,255}
\definecolor{Numbers}{rgb}{255,128,0}

\lstdefinestyle{mycode}{
  language=C,
  % Comments
  commentstyle=\color{Comments}\slshape,
  % Strings
  stringstyle=\color{Strings},
  % keywords
  keywordstyle={\color{Keywords}\bfseries}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=mycode]
int main ()
{
    //this is an example
    a1 = 0;
    a2 = a1;
    a3 = 16hxFF;
    a4 = 16 + a1;
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does [Coloring digits with the listings package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34896/), or [Listings package: How can I format all numbers?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32174/) help?

Comment: Thanks for linking those threads. However, neither addresses the issue of coloring numbers only after the equals sign. I've tried the solutions in both threads, but they still color numbers that occur to left of the = sign, which is not what I want.

Comment: So just to clarify: you want the _entire_ text of anything that starts with a digit following an equal sign (with possible a leading space) to be colored up until the closing semi-colon. No other digits are to be colored. So, can it be assumed that the "digits" that are to be colored restricted to `[a-fA-F0-9h]`?  Are there other characters that may show up here?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Reading your comment got me thinking more about the requirements and I've modified the question slightly. Any WORD after the equals sign that starts with a digit (0 - 9, a-f, A-F) should be colored. Coloring ends at the next semicolon OR SPACE. There's another example in my code that illustrates this as well.

Comment: You shoudl also adjust the text: "if the first digit after the equals sign is a number, all following digits until (but not including) the next semicolon are colored". Also can you provide a list of **all** the characters that are digits. You example include `h`. Any other characters?

Comment: There is also an issue with your comment: "...that starts with a digit", and since you include `a` in this list, then doesn't that mean that the `a1` should be colored? I think I know what you mean, but you should review to make sure that you have all the cases properly specd.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an adaptation of [Coloring digits with the listings package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34896/coloring-digits-with-the-listings-package):

[image]

### Notes:

- I have used `newtoggle` from [the `etoolbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox) as I prefer that syntax versus the `\newif` syntax. But if you don't want to include an additional package it should be pretty straightforward to adapt this to use `\newif` or [some other conditional methods](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build/33577#33577).

### Further Enhancements:

- This does **not** work if there is a non-digit within a number. So `16hxFF` will not be properly displayed, but `16x`   (with trailing space) is fine.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{Code}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{Keywords}{rgb}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{Strings}{rgb}{255,0,255}
\definecolor{Comments}{rgb}{0,0,255}
\definecolor{Numbers}{rgb}{255,128,0}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{AfterEqualSign}% Are we supposed to be coloring digits or not
\togglefalse{AfterEqualSign}% Wait until first equal sign
\newtoggle{AlreadyColoring}% Are we already coloring digits or not
\togglefalse{AlreadyColoring}% Start off with not coloring.

\newcommand*{\ColorIfDigitsAfterEqualSign}[1]{%
    \iftoggle{AfterEqualSign}{\color{orange}#1}{#1}%
    \global\toggletrue{AlreadyColoring}%
}%
\newcommand*{\ColorIfAlreadyColoring}[1]{%
    \iftoggle{AlreadyColoring}{%
        \color{orange}#1%
    }{%
        \global\togglefalse{AfterEqualSign}%
        #1%
    }%
}%
\newcommand*{\DisableColoring}[1]{%
    #1%
    \global\togglefalse{AlreadyColoring}%
    \global\togglefalse{AfterEqualSign}%
}%
\newcommand*{\DisableColoringIfAlreadyColoring}[1]{%
    % Allows for a leading space after the =, but before the number
    #1%
    \iftoggle{AlreadyColoring}{%
        \global\togglefalse{AfterEqualSign}%
        \global\togglefalse{AlreadyColoring}%
    }{}%
}%
\lstset{literate=%
    {=}{{{\global\toggletrue{AfterEqualSign}{=}}}}1% Encountered equal sign
    {0}{{{\ColorIfDigitsAfterEqualSign{0}}}}1
    {1}{{{\ColorIfDigitsAfterEqualSign{1}}}}1
    {2}{{{\ColorIfDigitsAfterEqualSign{2}}}}1
    {3}{{{\ColorIfDigitsAfterEqualSign{3}}}}1
    {4}{{{\ColorIfDigitsAfterEqualSign{4}}}}1
    {5}{{{\ColorIfDigitsAfterEqualSign{5}}}}1
    {6}{{{\ColorIfDigitsAfterEqualSign{6}}}}1
    {7}{{{\ColorIfDigitsAfterEqualSign{7}}}}1
    {8}{{{\ColorIfDigitsAfterEqualSign{8}}}}1
    {9}{{{\ColorIfDigitsAfterEqualSign{9}}}}1
    {a}{{{\ColorIfAlreadyColoring{a}}}}1
    {b}{{{\ColorIfAlreadyColoring{b}}}}1
    {c}{{{\ColorIfAlreadyColoring{c}}}}1
    {d}{{{\ColorIfAlreadyColoring{d}}}}1
    {e}{{{\ColorIfAlreadyColoring{e}}}}1
    {f}{{{\ColorIfAlreadyColoring{f}}}}1
    {h}{{{\ColorIfAlreadyColoring{h}}}}1% Add other characters here if needed
    {A}{{{\ColorIfAlreadyColoring{A}}}}1
    {B}{{{\ColorIfAlreadyColoring{B}}}}1
    {C}{{{\ColorIfAlreadyColoring{C}}}}1
    {D}{{{\ColorIfAlreadyColoring{D}}}}1
    {E}{{{\ColorIfAlreadyColoring{E}}}}1
    {F}{{{\ColorIfAlreadyColoring{F}}}}1
    {\ }{{{\DisableColoringIfAlreadyColoring{\ }}}}1% Disable coloring at trailing space
    {;}{{{\DisableColoring{;}}}}1% Disable coloring at semi colon
}

\lstdefinestyle{mycode} {
language=C,
  % Comments
  commentstyle=\color{Comments}\slshape,
  % Strings
  stringstyle=\color{Strings},
   % keywords
   keywordstyle={\color{Keywords}\bfseries}
   }

 \begin{document}

 \begin{lstlisting}[style=mycode]
 int main ()
{
    //this is an example
    a1 = 0;
    a2 = a1;
    a3 = 16hFF;
    a4 = 16 + a1;
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

### Review of Peter Grill's approach

[Peter's approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81702/21891) has its merits, but suffers from three limitations.

1. Any non-digit within a number breaks the highlighting of this number (as reported by Peter).
2. Numbers get partially highlighted within strings, which seems to be a bug; I guess numbers shouldn't be highlighted at all in strings.
3. `listings` is unable to recognise (and properly highlight) an identifier if the latter contains any character subject to a literate replacement. Here, for instance, `return` is not recognised as a keyword (and therefore not highlighted in red) because it contains the character `e`, which is subject to a literate replacement.

[image: Peter-Grill-approach]

### An alternative approach

Here is a similar but more robust approach, which remedies all three of the limitations discussed above. The only obvious problem is code duplication. **Edit**: see [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164447/21891) for a much leaner approach!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{Code}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{Keywords}{rgb}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{Strings}{rgb}{255,0,255}
\definecolor{Comments}{rgb}{0,0,255}
\definecolor{Numbers}{rgb}{255,128,0}

\makeatletter

\newif\iffirstchar\firstchartrue
\newif\ifstartedbyadigit
\newif\ifprecededbyequalsign

\newcommand\processletter
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
    \iffirstchar%
        \global\startedbyadigitfalse%
      \fi
      \global\firstcharfalse%
    \fi
}

\newcommand\processdigit
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
      \iffirstchar%
        \global\startedbyadigittrue%
      \fi
      \global\firstcharfalse%
  \fi
}

\lst@AddToHook{OutputOther}%
{%
  \lst@IfLastOtherOneOf{=}
    {\global\precededbyequalsigntrue}
    {}%
}

\lst@AddToHook{Output}%
{%
  \ifprecededbyequalsign%
      \ifstartedbyadigit%
        \def\lst@thestyle{\color{orange}}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \global\firstchartrue%
  \global\startedbyadigitfalse%
  \global\precededbyequalsignfalse%
}

\lstdefinestyle{mycode}
{
  language=C,
  commentstyle=\color{Comments}\slshape,
  stringstyle=\color{Strings},
  keywordstyle={\color{Keywords}\bfseries},
  alsoletter=0123456789,
  SelectCharTable=
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`0}\lsts@myzero{\lsts@myzero\processdigit}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`1}\lsts@myone{\lsts@myone\processdigit}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`2}\lsts@mytwo{\lsts@mytwo\processdigit}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`3}\lsts@mythree{\lsts@mythree\processdigit}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`4}\lsts@myfour{\lsts@myfour\processdigit}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`5}\lsts@myfive{\lsts@myfive\processdigit}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`6}\lsts@mysix{\lsts@mysix\processdigit}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`7}\lsts@myseven{\lsts@myseven\processdigit}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`8}\lsts@myeight{\lsts@myeight\processdigit}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`9}\lsts@mynine{\lsts@mynine\processdigit}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`a}\lsts@mya{\lsts@mya\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`b}\lsts@myb{\lsts@myb\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`c}\lsts@myc{\lsts@myc\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`d}\lsts@myd{\lsts@myd\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`e}\lsts@mye{\lsts@mye\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`f}\lsts@myf{\lsts@myf\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`g}\lsts@myg{\lsts@myg\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`h}\lsts@myh{\lsts@myh\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`i}\lsts@myi{\lsts@myi\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`j}\lsts@myj{\lsts@myj\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`k}\lsts@myk{\lsts@myk\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`l}\lsts@myl{\lsts@myl\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`m}\lsts@mym{\lsts@mym\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`n}\lsts@myn{\lsts@myn\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`o}\lsts@myo{\lsts@myo\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`p}\lsts@myp{\lsts@myp\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`q}\lsts@myq{\lsts@myq\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`r}\lsts@myr{\lsts@myr\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`s}\lsts@mys{\lsts@mys\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`t}\lsts@myt{\lsts@myt\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`u}\lsts@myu{\lsts@myu\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`v}\lsts@myv{\lsts@myv\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`w}\lsts@myw{\lsts@myw\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`x}\lsts@myx{\lsts@myx\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`y}\lsts@myy{\lsts@myy\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`z}\lsts@myz{\lsts@myz\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`A}\lsts@myA{\lsts@myA\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`B}\lsts@myB{\lsts@myB\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`C}\lsts@myC{\lsts@myC\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`D}\lsts@myD{\lsts@myD\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`E}\lsts@myE{\lsts@myE\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`F}\lsts@myF{\lsts@myF\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`G}\lsts@myG{\lsts@myG\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`H}\lsts@myH{\lsts@myH\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`I}\lsts@myI{\lsts@myI\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`J}\lsts@myJ{\lsts@myJ\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`K}\lsts@myK{\lsts@myK\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`L}\lsts@myL{\lsts@myL\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`M}\lsts@myM{\lsts@myM\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`N}\lsts@myN{\lsts@myN\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`O}\lsts@myO{\lsts@myO\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`P}\lsts@myP{\lsts@myP\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`Q}\lsts@myQ{\lsts@myQ\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`R}\lsts@myR{\lsts@myR\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`S}\lsts@myS{\lsts@myS\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`T}\lsts@myT{\lsts@myT\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`U}\lsts@myU{\lsts@myU\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`V}\lsts@myV{\lsts@myV\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`W}\lsts@myW{\lsts@myW\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`X}\lsts@myX{\lsts@myX\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`Y}\lsts@myY{\lsts@myY\processletter}
  \lst@DefSaveDef{`Z}\lsts@myZ{\lsts@myZ\processletter}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=mycode]
int main ()
{
    printf("foo 3a a3")
    //this is an example
    a1 = 0;
    a2 = a1;
    a3 = 16hxFF;
    a4 = 16 + a1;
    // sanity check
    a5 =+ 16hFF /* 16hFF is not highlighted because it's not
                   immediately preceded by an equal sign */
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your approach， but  how can I highlight for 'a_1 = 2' but not for 'a_1 = 1/b'

Comment: There's a color error in this answer though. See revision 3 in the linked answer for details.