# Set styles for numbers in listings package

Tags: listings, conditionals

I am using the listings package for Smalltalk programming language but since it does not come out of the box, I am trying to do it by hand. Now I have a problem with numbers. No matter if I change:

```
    numbersep=5pt,
numberstyle=\small\color{blue},
```

it is not taken into account, that is, they do not change. I know I can do:

```
\lstset{literate=%
{0}{{{\myNumberStyle{0}}}}1
{1}{{{\myNumberStyle{1}}}}1
{2}{{{\myNumberStyle{2}}}}1
{3}{{{\myNumberStyle{3}}}}1
{4}{{{\myNumberStyle{4}}}}1
{5}{{{\myNumberStyle{5}}}}1
{6}{{{\myNumberStyle{6}}}}1
{7}{{{\myNumberStyle{7}}}}1
{8}{{{\myNumberStyle{8}}}}1
{9}{{{\myNumberStyle{9}}}}1
```

}

However, that affects ALL numbers, even if they are inside strings or comments. I only want to applyt the style to numbers when they are NOT in strings or comments or whatever..just when they are "alone"

For the record, here is all my settings:

```
  \lstset{
language={},
% characters
tabsize=3,
escapechar={!},
keepspaces=true,
breaklines=true,
alsoletter={\#},
breakautoindent=true,
columns=fullflexible,
showstringspaces=false,
% background
frame=single,
aboveskip=1em, % automatic space before
framerule=0pt,
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=\myKeywordStyle,% keyword style
commentstyle=\myCommentStyle,% comment style
frame=single,%
backgroundcolor=\color{source},
% numbering
numbersep=5pt,
numberstyle=\small\color{blue},
numberfirstline=true,
% caption
captionpos=b,
% formatting (html)
moredelim=[is][\textbf]{<b>}{</b>},
moredelim=[is][\textit]{<i>}{</i>},
moredelim=[is][\uline]{<u>}{</u>},
moredelim=[is][\color{red}\uwave]{<wave>}{</wave>},
moredelim=[is][\color{red}\sout]{<del>}{</del>},
moredelim=[is][\color{blue}\uline]{<ins>}{</ins>},
% smalltalk stuff
    morecomment=[s][\myCommentStyle]{"}{"},%
    morecomment=[s][\myvs]{|}{|},  
morestring=[b][\myStringStyle]', 
moredelim=[is][]{<sel>}{</sel>},
moredelim=[is][]{<rcv>}{</rcv>},
moredelim=[is][\itshape]{<symb>}{</symb>},
moredelim=[is][\scshape]{<class>}{</class>},
morekeywords={true,false,nil,self,super,thisContext},
identifierstyle=\idstyle,
}


     \makeatletter
    \newcommand*\idstyle[1]{%
     \expandafter\id@style\the\lst@token{#1}\relax%
  }
  \def\id@style#1#2\relax{%
       \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{\#}=0%
            % this is a symbol
            \mySymbolStyle{\the\lst@token}%
        \else%
          \edef\tempa{\uccode`#1}%
          \edef\tempb{`#1}%
          \ifnum\tempa=\tempb%
          % this is a global
          \myGlobalStyle{\the\lst@token}%
          \else%
              \the\lst@token%
         \fi%
        \fi%
 }
  \makeatother
```

Any ideas?  thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution in [How can I change the color of digits when using the listings package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23634/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-digits-when-using-the-listings-package)

putting a star at the beginning:

```
\lstset{literate=%
    *{0}{{{\myNumberStyle{0}}}}1
    {1}{{{\myNumberStyle{1}}}}1
    {2}{{{\myNumberStyle{2}}}}1
    {3}{{{\myNumberStyle{3}}}}1
    {4}{{{\myNumberStyle{4}}}}1
    {5}{{{\myNumberStyle{5}}}}1
    {6}{{{\myNumberStyle{6}}}}1
    {7}{{{\myNumberStyle{7}}}}1
    {8}{{{\myNumberStyle{8}}}}1
    {9}{{{\myNumberStyle{9}}}}1
}
```