# vim type Display for C Code in Latex

Tags: formatting, listings

**Target Display:**

[image]

**My Latex Code:**

```
% xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Code Snippet STARTS xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\lstset{
  language=C,                     % choose the language of the code
  stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
 % numbersep=5pt,                 % how far the line-numbers are from the code
%  backgroundcolor=\color{white}, % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
  showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
  showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
  showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  tabsize=4,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  captionpos=t,                   % sets the caption-position to top
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
  breakatwhitespace=true,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
 % title=\lstname,                % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting;
 identifierstyle=\color{black},
 caption={Array of Pointers to Strings},
 frame=lrtb,
 %keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{OliveGreen},         % keyword style
 keywordstyle=[1]\bfseries\color{OliveGreen},
 % Define TYPE-1 Keywords
 keywords=[1]{
    int, char,float, double, unsigned, signed,
    goto},
 % Define TYPE-2 Keywords
 keywordstyle=[2]\bfseries\color{Violet},
  keywords=[2]{
  %s, %d, 
  include, define},
 % Define TYPE-3 Keywords
 keywordstyle=[3]\bfseries\color{Sepia},
  keywords=[3]{
    return},
 commentstyle=\bfseries\color{blue},   % comment style
 stringstyle= \color{Magenta!80},          % string literal style
 belowcaptionskip = 0.2in,                % Space below caption
 abovecaptionskip = 0.2in                 % Space above caption
}
\begin{lstlisting}

#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 4

int main()
{
    char *strings[SIZE] = 
                      {
                        "String1", 
                        "String2",
                        "String3",
                        "String4"
                      };

    char *ptr_swap;   /* A temporary pointer to swap strings */

    /* Swap "String2" with "String3" */
    ptr_swap  = strings [1];
    strings [1] = strings [2];                    
    strings [2] = ptr_swap;


    printf ("%s %s %s %s", strings[0], strings[1], strings[2], strings[3]);

    return 0;
} 

\end{lstlisting}
% xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Code Snippet ENDS xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

My Output is as follows:

The fields marked under Red Line have Different Formatting from the Target.

[image]

- Please help me correct these settings so that I can get the desired 'gvim' like output.
- How can I specify keywordstyle for **Format Specifiers** since, putting:
  %s, %d -> make the statement commented?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please always add a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

I think, you need something like that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Now to your problem. If you look into `listings/lstlang1.sty` you will see, that `#include` is not a `keyword`, but a `directive`. So you can say

```
...
  directivestyle=\bfseries\color{Violet},
...
```

and all those `#...` directives are colored in violet.

With `%s` that is another problem. You could escape `%s` as `\%` and give the option `alsoletter={\%}`. But keywords are generally not highlighted in strings. So this would highlight a free-floating `%s`, but not the ones in your example and also not other expressions like `%03d`, which can be used in `printf`.

There is a solution for this too, but only because of a bug in the `listings` package. (Compare also [this thread](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2320&start=0)) You can give `%s` as `otherkeyword` and it will get highlighted in strings. As `otherkeyword` is automatically in keyword group 1, you will have to move the regular keywords into another group, as they should be styled differently.

Numbers can be colored as in [How can I change the color of digits when using the listings package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23634/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-digits-when-using-the-listings-package). Notice also the comment there on how to have no highlight in comments.

The `<stdio.h>` is basically a string. So you can just put `<` and `>` as new string delimiters. But be careful that you have to escape them if they would occur elsewhere.

I can't say right now how you could highlight constants after `#define` like `SIZE`. (If it is even possible)

So all in all you will have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\def\digitcolor{\color{Magenta!80}}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
  language=C,                     % choose the language of the code
  stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
 % numbersep=5pt,                 % how far the line-numbers are from the code
%  backgroundcolor=\color{white}, % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
  showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
  showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
  showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  tabsize=4,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  captionpos=t,                   % sets the caption-position to top
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
  breakatwhitespace=true,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
 % title=\lstname,                % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting;
 identifierstyle=\color{black},
 caption={Array of Pointers to Strings},
 frame=lrtb,
 % Define TYPE-1 Keywords
 directivestyle=\bfseries\color{Violet},
 keywords={},
 otherkeywords={\%s, \%d},
 keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{Violet},
 keywordstyle=[2]\bfseries\color{OliveGreen},
 % Define TYPE-2 Keywords
 keywords=[2]{
    auto,break,case,char,const,continue,default,do,double,%
  else,enum,extern,float,for,goto,if,int,long,register,%
  short,signed,sizeof,static,struct,switch,typedef,union,unsigned,%
  void,volatile,while},
%    int, char,float, double, unsigned, signed,
%    goto},
 % Define TYPE-3 Keywords
 keywordstyle=[3]\bfseries\color{Sepia},
  keywords=[3]{
    return},
    literate=*%
    {0}{{{\digitcolor0}}}1
    {1}{{{\digitcolor1}}}1
    {2}{{{\digitcolor2}}}1
    {3}{{{\digitcolor3}}}1
    {4}{{{\digitcolor4}}}1
    {5}{{{\digitcolor5}}}1
    {6}{{{\digitcolor6}}}1
    {7}{{{\digitcolor7}}}1
    {8}{{{\digitcolor8}}}1
    {9}{{{\digitcolor9}}}1,
 commentstyle=\bfseries\color{blue},   % comment style
 morestring=[b]{<},
 morestring=[b]{>},
 stringstyle= \color{Magenta!80},          % string literal style
 belowcaptionskip = 0.2in,                % Space below caption
 abovecaptionskip = 0.2in                 % Space above caption
}
\begin{lstlisting}

#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 4

int main()
{
    char *strings[SIZE] = 
                      {
                        "String1", 
                        "String2",
                        "String3",
                        "String4"
                      };

    char *ptr_swap;   /* A temporary pointer to swap strings */

    /* Swap "String2" with "String3" */
    ptr_swap  = strings [1];
    strings [1] = strings [2];                    
    strings [2] = ptr_swap;

    printf ("%s %s %s %s", strings[0], strings[1], strings[2], strings[3]);

    return 0;
} 

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: resulting output]

Comment: The effects of  "morestring=[b]{<},
 morestring=[b]{>}," are disasterous. If I have a for loop like: for (i=0; i<4,...) => This will make EVERYTHING starting from '<' => a String. The entire remaining code will be displayed as a string. Is there any alternative workaround? I tried many combinations, but none seems to work.

Comment: @SandeepSingh: That is true. I thought, when reading the documentation, that you can escape those other `<` and `>`, but it seems you can only escape string delimiters inside of other strings. I don't know an easy solution for this problem. You could define `morecomment[l][\color{Magenta!80}]{\#include}`, but then you need to change the color of `#include` back. Maybe http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2008-07/msg00216.html helps there. But before going to such lengths it is probably a good idea to try the `minted` package.