# listings: Changing the meaning of underscore for the language R (customizing a language)

Tags: listings

I really like the `listings` package but often it drives me crazy :). I want to have listings of the programming language R (statistic stuff). Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=R,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{red}\bfseries,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
my_Variable <- qnorm(0.05/2, mean=0, sd=1)
>> 1.959964
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Here's the result:
[image]

Here's the **problem**:

1. Even in the **comment** the **dash** is **highlighted**.
2. The **underscore** in the Variable name is **highlighted** too.

I have tried to use the `deletekeywords={_,/}` option - but without success. I also tried `alsoletter`. Maybe someone could point out my mistake.

**EDIT 1:**
If it's possible I do not want to change the actual code (listing) as in the first answer. Because then the code won't be suitable for my programming language (in my case R) any more.

**EDIT 2:**
Any help is appreciated. How can I make it easier to help?

### Conclusion

- According to the (very good) accepted answer this is caused by a bug in `listings`.
- Other examples for the same bug seem to be [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67437) and [this](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2320&start=0).

Comment: Have you considered `knitr` or `sweave`? With either of these the source document contains both the runnable R code and the LaTeX text.

Comment: @Ethan: Hello Ethan, thanks for the hint. I will consider this in the next project - right now I want to meet the deadline :). I just want to include R code as it is and it should look pretty in the listing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The R language highlighting is defined in `lstdrvrs.dtx`.  If you look there, you will find

```
otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,*,\&,\%/\%,\%*\%,\%\%,<-,<<-,_,/}
```

So you just need to add that to your `\lstset` to overwrite the defaults, but with the underscore and slash removed:

```
otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,*,\&,\%/\%,\%*\%,\%\%,<-,<<-}
```

Doing this will prevent the slash and underscore from ever being highlighted, though, so this won't work if you need them to be highlighted in other contexts.  Just to make things uniform between division and multiplication, you may also wish to remove the asterisk `*` from the list.  (You might need to remove a few other things as well to keep math in general uniform; I don't know R.)

Unfortunately, Pygments doesn't seem to offer as much as `listings` in terms of keyword highlighting for R, so if that's what you need, Pygments-based highlighting packages like `minted` and `pythontex` may not be an alternative (at least, not without writing a custom lexer).

Comment: Thanks. This is very useful. Is it normal that listings highlights in comments?

Comment: Regular keywords (such as defined by `morekeywords`) don't highlight in comments.  But it seems that anything in `otherkeywords` will be highlighted anywhere.  This is apparently a bug in listings (here's another [reference](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67437/vim-type-display-for-c-code-in-latex) to it).

Comment: @Pooer: Ok - thanks. Do you think a bug report has a chance to get noticed?

Comment: You might file a bug report, but listings hasn't had a new release since 2007.  That's part of the reason I added Pygments-based highlighting to my `pythontex` package; I want a powerful highlighting solution that's under active development.

Comment: Very cool. I haven't heared about it yet. I neet to install additional software as I understand it. I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: I just revisited your answer and again thank you for it!

Answer (score 4):

You can seek shelter inside `escapeinside` option as below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=R,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{red}\bfseries,
    escapeinside=||
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
my|\_|Variable <- qnorm(0.05/2, mean=0, sd=1)
# even inside comments |/| doesn't highlight.
>> 1.959964
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a very comfortable way -- thank you very much! I didn't use `escapeinside` yet. Cool! But this is a kind of work around? This solution changes into LaTeX mode - right? I'll wait a bit - maybe there is another way without changing the listing. Because the listing is not suitable to be used in R anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You should also look at the option `alsoletter` in case you want to add highlighting for the Hadley functions. This defines which characters are considered to be also a letter (and hence can be part of a name as well).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=R,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{red}\bfseries,
    alsoletter ={_},
    otherkeywords = {!,!=,~,$,*,\&,\%/\%,\%*\%,\%\%,<-,<<-},
    morekeywords = {str_extract}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
my_Variable <- qnorm(0.05/2, mean=0, sd=1)
# even inside comments _ doesn't highlight.
str_extract("Hello", "e")
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just adding this here as I had that exact problem and ended up on this question in search for a solution.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner It pointed me to the hidden problem of the `otherkeywords` defined for R, so explained me why my attempt to use `alsoletters` didn't work the first time. It was helpful indeed :-)