# Emphasize digits with listings

Tags: listings

Is there any method to emphasize digits with `listings`?

For example, I want to make the number `3.0` and `4.0` to be orange like this:

[image]

(From TensorFlow website.)

I have tried options `emph` and `emphstyle`, but they can only emphasize identifiers like `int32` or `node1`, while pure numbers can't be emphasized.

Using the codes from [Peter Grill's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34952/136923) or [Herbert's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23638/136923), however, digits in identifiers ('32' in `int32`) will also be colored. On the other hand, the dot in `3.0` is still unemphasized.

Comment: Possible duplicate(s): [`listings` package: How can I format all numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32174/5764); [Coloring digits with the `listings` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34896/5764); [How can I change the color of digits when using the `listings` package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23634/5764)

Comment: How about numbers like `3.0`, `-5` or even `1.2e3`?