# Why lstlisting does not highlight numbers?

Tags: listings, code

I would like to include some python code in my document, and here is what I have written so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0.04314,0.6745,0.07843}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.7059,0.6863,0.702}
\definecolor{codered}{rgb}{0.5373,0.02745,0.06275}
\definecolor{codeblue}{rgb}{0.071,0.0258,0.9882}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.6,0.02745,0.5961}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    commentstyle=\color{codegray},
    keywordstyle=\color{codepurple},
    otherkeywords={range, print, max, len},
    classoffset=1, % starting new class
    keywordstyle=\color{codeblue},
    numberstyle=\color{codered},
    stringstyle=\color{codegreen},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
        sd.play(audio.astype('int16'))

        paso = 5
        for i in range(0,ntramas,paso):
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I would want the code to appear like this:

[image]

However, this is what I get in latex:

[image]

The difference is in the colour of numbers, which appear in black despite I have indicated with the `numberstyle` sentence I want them in red.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Doesn't `numberstyle` refer to line numbers as opposed to numbers inside of the code?

Comment: You might be interested in [How can I change the color of digits when using the listings package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23634/134144)

Comment: I thought `numberstyle` was for numbers, but you are totally right. My apologies and thank you