redefine color pattern of listings language
I would like to redefine language color patter like below:

Below code works for some elements, but the numberstyle color not work
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{stringcol}{HTML}{2AA198}
\definecolor{directivecol}{HTML}{C5C680}
\definecolor{commentcol}{HTML}{586E75}
\definecolor{identifiercol}{HTML}{569CD6}
\definecolor{numbercol}{HTML}{D33682}
\definecolor{variablecol}{HTML}{268BD2}
\definecolor{keywordcol}{HTML}{859900}
\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{1.5\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[
    frame=tb,
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\huge\bfseries\color{white},
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!100},
    numberstyle=\color{numbercol},
    keywordstyle=\color{keywordcol},
    directivestyle=\color{directivecol},
    stringstyle=\color{stringcol},
    identifierstyle=\color{identifiercol},
    commentstyle=\color{commentcol}
    ]

#include <stdio.h>
// main function
int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        if (i == 3) printf("Hello world!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

\end{lstlisting}
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}



Output:


For the invisible characters: Use basicstyle=\color{white} to make them visible.

Thanks,@Skillmon, the I got default color, but the numberstyle define not work. I have updated the code.

@lucky1928 numberstyle works, but your example does not show any line numbers, so you won't see. If you enable line numbers, you can see that they changed colour: https://i.sstatic.net/oTXIbYwA.png

@lucky1928 If you could like to change the colour of the numbers within your code, then see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23638/36296

That one not answer numberstyle question. and that one can not handle test3 variable case.
